# Quota limit google currency converter api

Tags: google-api, quotas

I have been using Google API for Currency Converter :

```
https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency
```

Just wanted to know if there is any quota limitations for using the above service?

I found the Google analytics Quota limit guideline, but not sure if it is the same for currency converter.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/limits-quotas#general_api

Please point me the exact information regarding currency converter API's quota limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can see any quota limits and traffic information in your [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com). Just go to the APIs tab and there will be quota information. If you look at a specific API, there should be a tab for quota, assuming that the API is enabled and in use. However, it seems this Currency Converter API is not an official Google API, so there is no documentation for it nor is it listed in the APIs you can enable on the developer console. Unfortunately, I do not think any official information concerning the Currency Converter API's quota limit exists.

Answer (score 0):

For all Google API Services, You have Only 10,000 requests per view (profile) per day